# Verbs "may" and "let" used to wish somebody something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> May all your dreams come true!
>
> Let all your dreams come true!

Both seem to have the same meaning. Is there any difference? Are they interchangeable? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a huge difference between the two

> **May** all your dreams come true.

is a wish for *someone's* dreams to be fulfilled, without any intervention by the listener.

> **Let** all you dreams come true.

implies that the listener may be doing *something* which is stopping their dreams from being realized and they needs to stop doing that to "let" their dreams happen.

Comment: Oh, Peter, thanks a lot. So if I wish it to somebody it's better to say "may", right?

Answer (score 1):

May all your dreams come true!

Let all your dreams come true.

There's a difference in meaning between the sentences.

The former is a sort of supplication;  "may" can be used to express a strong wish.

The latter is a sort of suggestion; "let" can be used to mean to allow something to happen without stopping it, or to make it possible for something to happen.

Comment: I don't quite understand when to use "let"

Comment: @V.V.,  to let means to allow or permit something to happen. Let your hair grow..